# How do I use pexcept to send local AND remote commands

Tags: python-3.x, pexpect

I have a simple class that allows me to send tons of local CLI commands.  Allowing me to test certain command line functions.  The mechanism works wonderfully but needs to be extended.  I am stumped on how to change this mechanism to handle both local or remote commands.

```
from pexpect import *
class Expect( ):
    def Do( self, cmd, program: list = [], timeout = 20 ):
        result = run( cmd, events=program, timeout=timeout).decode() 
        return result

cmd  = 'login'
prog = [('username \\(.+\\):', 'yourUN\n'), ('password:', 'yourPW\n')]
res  = Expect().Do( cmd, prog )    # Returns everything
print( 'res: ' + res )
# use results to verify functionality
```

Returns something like:

```
username (root):yourUN
password:*****
Logged in user yourUN
```

I currently have over 1250 tests running some 5000 cli local commands. The only issue is that I need this class to support local commands as well as remote SSH commands.

I have set up my test machines to allow remote SSH without user SSH login.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, and based on my tests, you will need two functions or methods.

**1.** The first function runs local commands using Pexpect. You can also run ssh commands using the first function, but only if the IP address exists in the `known_hosts` file:

`pexpect.run("ssh yourUN@192.168.x.x 'whoami'")`

Otherwise, you will run into a `"The authenticity of host '192.168.x.x (192.168.x.x)' can't be established."` error.

**2.** To avoid that error, I recommend a second function for ssh commands that uses Paramiko.

Here is the complete code:

> **NOTE** - Tested on Linux 5.14.16 using Python 3.9. Remote machine is Ubuntu 8.04.

```
from getpass import getpass

import paramiko
import pexpect


def run_cli_commands(list_of_commands, password=None):
    for c in list_of_commands:
        print("Command:", c)
        command_output, exitstatus = pexpect.run(
            c,
            events={"(?i)password": password if password is not None else getpass()},
            withexitstatus=True)
        print("Output:\n", command_output.decode())


def run_ssh_commands(list_of_commands, ip_address, username, password):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ip_address, username=username, password=password)
    for c in list_of_commands:
        print("Command:", c)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(c)
        print("Output:\n", stdout.read().decode())


run_cli_commands(["which ssh",
                  "systemctl status ssh",
                  "systemctl start ssh",
                  "systemctl status ssh", ], password="**********")
run_ssh_commands(["whoami",
                  "date", ], "192.168.x.x", "yourUN", "**********")
run_cli_commands(["systemctl stop ssh", ], password="**********")
print("Script complete. Have a nice day.")
```

**Output:**

```
Local command: which ssh
Output:
 /usr/bin/ssh

Local command: systemctl status ssh
Output:
 ○ ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)

Local command: systemctl start ssh
Output:
 
Local command: systemctl status ssh
Output:
 ● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-12-09 23:13:05 EST; 174ms ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
    Process: 4565 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/sshd -t (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 4566 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 2275)
     Memory: 2.3M
        CPU: 18ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             └─4566 "sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups"

SSH command: whoami
Output:
 yourUN

SSH command: date
Output:
 Thu Dec  9 23:13:04 EST 2021

Local command: systemctl stop ssh
Output:
 
Script complete. Have a nice day.
```